# how to grab database name form config in codeigniter and run a sql file to insert tables into database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Want to grab a `database` name from `config/database.php`. 
I have written this `code`. but it not works.

```
$dbname = $_POST['dbname'];    
$db =  $this->db->database;
       if($dbname == $db)
          {
            $template = 'application/views/install/db/dbwrite.sql'; 
            $template_path =  set_realpath($template);
            $result = $this->db->query(file_get_contents($template_path)); 
          }
    $this->load->view('login');
```

After this when I select the `database` name then I want to execute this SQL file `dbwrite.sql` to create a table in the database automatically.

dbwrite.sql

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not works"? What happens instead?

Comment: actually, the if statement not runs.

Comment: May be you are not posting exact db name

Comment: No, the db name is same in both $dbname = $_POST['dbname'];   $db =  $this->db->database; and also in the database. the connection works perfectly. but here the if statements not executed.

Comment: you mean your post dbname and $db is not matched? or something else

Comment: @M.Hemant yes bro.

Comment: can you show us your $_POST in var_dump()?

Comment: So, what have you tried to debug this? Please dump both `$_POST['dbname']` and `$db`

Comment: @NicoHaase I var_dump both $_POST['dbname'] and $db which has same value of 'studentPortal'. studentPortal is the database name.

Comment: Can you share the **exact** output? If they are equal, what have you tried to debug further? Is `$this->db->query` really not executed? How did you check that?

Comment: the code inside the if statement not executed. but when I write this code outside the if statement. then it executes but gives that error. 'No Database selected'.

Comment: so first I want to select the database and check it with $_POST['name'] if they are same then i want to execute $this->db->query().

Comment: Is `$this->db->database` valid CI code? I'm not sure I've seen this before. Simply output `$this->db->database` and `$_POST['dbname']` and see what appears. Have you created the database on your server?

Comment: @Antony yes I have created the database on the server.